# AS3/Adobe AIR Error with Orientation

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

After opening the native modal window(of social network) (and rotating iOS device in landscape) and closing it again. App is still in portrait, as it is designed to be, but the viewport is shifted down about half the screen (496 pixels, to be precise: behind the game center overlay, the stage gets rotated into landscape, so only the top 640 px (screen width) are visible. Use:

```
 <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
<renderMode>direct</renderMode>
<visible>true</visible>
<aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
```

and in app:

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
App should stay in portrait orientation. What I can do?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/vDr8vYeiJqaW26

Comment: <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>

Comment: use flex sdk 4.6.0.23201 air 17.0.0.123